# Debugging class libraries, Visual Studio automation

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, automation

I'm debugging a class library which is testing by a demo application. Each time I make a change in code and set a break-point I should:

1. Compile code
2. Run demo executable
3. Attach debugger to demo.exe process

Can I automate these steps in some way ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right-click your class library project, Set as Startup Project if necessary.  Again, Properties, Debug tab.  Select "Start external program" and select your 'demo' program's EXE.

Pressing F5 now automatically starts the demo program with the debugger attached.  Don't forget to take advantage of Edit+Continue.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a demo application. Just create unit test for the library. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379625(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Demo application is more complicated than you think. It's not wise to write a unit test and related mock objects in my case.

Comment: Well, if both projects are in the same solution, you can run the demo application once. VS will hit breakpoints inside the library's source file. BTW, I'm not sure if it's a mandatory to have both projects in one solution. So you will skip step 3

Comment: @Xaqron: I have lots of services and it's actually not wise for me NOT to write unit tests and mocks. Especially mocks because the database data is very volatile. If you are developer and that's how you want to write your tests then you really need to re-evaluate your approach.

Comment: Yes, previous comment was @ Schultz. I don't have access to demo.exe code. Maybe it's not written in .NET